# Control Multiple Google Sheets through a common Library instead of code.gs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a project that automates price book information.  All of the code controlling the data validation and handling sits in the code.gs file.  The sheet works quite well and now we have 54 sheets (one for each supplier).  All of these sheets are a copy of the original.

Where the challenge comes in is if we make a code change, we currently have to make the changes and test in a "template" copy of the current version.  Once tested and approved, we then have to make 54 copies using the new template.

Is there a way to share a common code.gs file where we could manage all iterations of the project "books"

Comment: If you had a list of spreadsheet ids you could load all of the code for each spreadsheet with one script utilizing features found in [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest)

Comment: I will check this out.  I assume this would also work for updating code changes as they come out.

Comment: You can deploy the Apps Script as a private [Add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/editors/sheets), and do the test in the original. Once you are happy with the change, you can [deploy a new version](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/update-published-add-on) of the Add-on to all the other sheets.